# HTML 5 how to record filtered canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, ffmpeg

I am gonna use my webcam as a source and show my view on webpage , than I will manipulate my view like (blacknwhite , fiseye, etc.) and show that manipulated video in my canvas. 
An example ( http://photobooth.orange-coding.net/ )

Ok everything is cool for now . I can capture that manipulated canvas as a image.

Is there any way to record that manipulated canvas as video?

I also found an example (https://www.webrtc-experiment.com/ffmpeg/audio-plus-canvas-recording.html)

But when I tried that code on my webcam recording project , it's just recording my source view(not blacknwhite) . It is not implementing my effect to record.

Any idea or is it possible ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recording video in the browser is like getting blood out of a stone. If you hit it hard and long enough against your head, there will be blood, eventually. But it's a painful experience, you it will certainly give you a headache!

There is currently no way of recording video in *real-time* from a canvas element. But there is proposed a **[Mediastream Recording API](http://www.w3.org/TR/mediastream-recording/)** which includes video (and it excludes the canvas part). Currently only audio is supported, and only if FF.

You *can* grab an image as often as possible and use it as a sequence, but there are several issues you will run into:

- You will not get full frame-rate if you choose to grab the image as JPEG or PNG (PNG is not very useful with video as there is no alpha)
- If you choose to grab the raw data you may achieve full frame rate (note that frame rate for video is typically never above 30 FPS) but you will fill up the memory very quickly, and you would need a point in time to process the frames into something that can be transferred to server or downloaded. JavaScript is single threaded and no matter how you twist and turn this stage, you will get gaps in the video when this process is invoked (unless you have a lot of memory and can wait until the end - but this not good for a public available solution if that's the goal).
- You will have no proper sinc like time-code (to sync by) so the video will be like the movies from Chaplins day, variable. You can get close by binding high-resolution timestamps but not accurate enough as you will have no way of getting the stamp at the very time you grab the image.
- No sound is recorded; if you *do* record audio in FF using the API, you have no way to properly sync the audio with the video anyways (which already has its own problems ref. above)
- Up until now we are still at *single frame* sequences. If you record one minute @ 30 fps you have 60x30 frames, or 1800 pictures/buffers per minute. If you record in HD720 and choose grabbing the raw buffer (the most realistic option here) you will end up with 1800 x 1280 x 720 x 4 (RGBA) bytes per minute, or 6,635,520,000 bytes, ie. 6.18 GB per minute - and that's just in raw size. Even if you lower the resolution to lets say 720x480 you'll end up with 2.32 GB/min.
- You can alternatively process them into a video format, it's possible, but currently there are next to none solutions for this (there has been one, but it had varying result which is probably why it's hard be found...), so you are left to this yourselves - and that is a complete project involving writing encoder, compressor etc. And the memory usage will be quite high as you need to create each frame in separate buffers until you know the full length, then create a storage buffer to hold them all and so forth. And even if you did, compressing more than 6 GB worth of data (or event "just" 2 GB) is not gonna make user or browser very happy (if there is any memory left)...
- Or bite the dust and go with a **[commercial Flash based solution](https://hdfvr.com/features)** (but that excludes your image processing and pretty much takes over the camera... so not really an option in this case).

The only realistic option, IMO, is to wait for the aforementioned API - this will let your browser do all the hard work, in compiled optimized code, enable frame by frame compression leaving the memory pretty much intact, and give very little headache compared to the alternative(s) above. There may be an option to apply shaders to the stream at one point, or integrate it with some canvas processing (not on the table in this proposal AFAICS) so recording real-time from a canvas will still be a challenge.

This is where server side processing comes in...

(of course, a screen recorder is an option which is of curse completely non-integrated, but will enable you to demo your effects at least...).

Comment: Thank you for your great answer , I exaclty experienced almost all of these issues you wrote about. Now I am just recording video and audio with Mediastream Recording API as you said. And converting them into mp4 with https://www.ffmpeg.org/. But I will try screen recording for my effects but as you said it is hard to sync audio and screen video get together. (Y)